# Program terminates after one of the cases is completed but does not for the others

Tags: c++, menu, switch-statement

The program terminates after one of the cases is completed but does not for the others. I need this programs menu to loop until the user enters 'q', however, it terminates after case 'a' only, the others still loop. I included all the cases and the menu just in case the error is not inside the 'Add Song' case.

```
while (choice != 'q') {
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << play << " PLAYLIST MENU" << endl;
    cout << "a - Add song" << endl;
    cout << "d - Remove song" << endl;
    cout << "c - Change position of song" << endl;
    cout << "s - Output songs by specific artist" << endl;
    cout << "t - Output total time of playlist (in seconds)" << endl;
    cout << "o - Output full playlist" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Choose an option:";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch (choice) {
    case 'a':
        {
            cout << "ADD SONG" << endl;

            cout << "Enter song's unique ID: ";
            cin >> uniqueID;
            cout << endl << "Enter song's name: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, songName);
            cout << endl << "Enter artist's name: ";
            getline(cin, artistName);
            cout << endl << "Enter song's length (in seconds): ";
            cin >> songLength;

            if (headList == NULL) {
                headList = tailList;
                tailList -> SetNext(new PlaylistNode(uniqueID, songName, artistName, songLength));
            } else {
                tailList -> SetNext(new PlaylistNode(uniqueID, songName, artistName, songLength));
                tailList = tailList -> GetNext();
            }
            break;
        }

    case 'd':
        {
            cout << "REMOVE SONG" << endl;

            cout << "Enter song's unique ID: ";
            cin >> uniqueID;

            currList = headList;
            prevList = headList;

            while (currList != NULL) {
                if (currList -> GetID() == uniqueID) {
                    if (currList == headList) {
                        headList = headList -> GetNext();

                        if (currList == tailList) {
                            tailList = NULL;
                        }
                    } else if (tailList == currList) {
                        tailList = prevList;
                        tailList -> SetNext(NULL);
                    } else {
                        prevList -> SetNext(currList -> GetNext());
                    }
                    break;
                }
                prevList = currList;
                currList = currList -> GetNext();
            }
            break;
        }

    case 'c':
        {
            cout << "CHANGE POSITION OF SONG" << endl;

            cout << "Enter song's current position: ";
            cin >> curPos;
            cout << "Enter new position for song: ";
            cin >> newPos;
            break;

        case 's':
                cout << "OUTPUT SONGS BY SPECIFIC ARTIST" << endl;

            cout << "Enter artist's name: ";
            getline(cin, artistName);

            currList = headList;
            position = 1;

            while (currList != NULL) {
                if (currList -> GetArtistName() == artistName) {
                    cout << position << "." << endl;
                    cout << "Unique ID: " << currList -> GetID() << endl;
                    cout << "Song Name: " << currList -> GetSongName() << endl;
                    cout << "Artist Name: " << currList -> GetArtistName() << endl;
                    cout << "Song Length (in seconds): " << currList -> GetSongLength() << endl;
                }
                currList = currList -> GetNext();
                position++;
            }
            break;
        }
    case 't':
        {
            cout << "OUTPUT TOTAL TIME OF PLAYLIST (IN SECONDS)" << endl;

            int totalLength = 0;
            currList = headList;

            while (currList != NULL) {
                totalLength += currList -> GetSongLength();
                currList = currList -> GetNext();
            }
            cout << "Total time: " << totalLength << " seconds" << endl;
            break;
        }
    case 'o':
        {
            cout << play << " - OUTPUT FULL PLAYLIST" << endl;

            if (headList == NULL) {
                cout << "Playlist is empty" << endl;
                break;
            }

            position = 1;
            currList = headList;

            cout << position << "." << endl;
            cout << "Unique ID: " << currList -> GetID() << endl;
            cout << "Song Name: " << currList -> GetSongName() << endl;
            cout << "Artist Name: " << currList -> GetArtistName() << endl;
            cout << "Song Length (in seconds): " << currList -> GetSongLength() << endl;

            currList = currList -> GetNext();
            position++;

            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The choice of indentation makes the control flow hard to follow.

Comment: Yeah I apologize for that. I originally wrote it in puTTy but the assignment changed and I was forced to bring it into zybooks, some of the formatting got messed up in the process.

Comment: the error is not in the `cout` statements ;) Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: After fixing the indentation, it looks like your return is outside the loop? Seems your code blocks are not aligned and out of scope for a lot of things. Fix that and try it again. Look at `case 's'`

Comment: the intendation of code reflects its logical structure, mess up one of the two and you get the other messed up for free

Comment: As silly as this sounds, you have the core of an answer there, @clinomaniac . I don't think approving your edit is in the best interests of this question as the broken indentation effectively IS the bug. Consider posting your edited code as an answer with the places where the bad indentation resulted in an error brightly marked and explained if the problem isn't obvious.

Comment: @user4581301 Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the indentation of your code:

You'll see that the broken part in the code around `case 's':` is not aligned with the rest of the case statements. That's because the `}` is missing from the previous `case`. I believe that is the cause of your issue.

```
while (choice != 'q') {
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << play << " PLAYLIST MENU" << endl;
    cout << "a - Add song" << endl;
    cout << "d - Remove song" << endl;
    cout << "c - Change position of song" << endl;
    cout << "s - Output songs by specific artist" << endl;
    cout << "t - Output total time of playlist (in seconds)" << endl;
    cout << "o - Output full playlist" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Choose an option:";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch (choice) {
    case 'a':
        {
            cout << "ADD SONG" << endl;

            cout << "Enter song's unique ID: ";
            cin >> uniqueID;
            cout << endl << "Enter song's name: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, songName);
            cout << endl << "Enter artist's name: ";
            getline(cin, artistName);
            cout << endl << "Enter song's length (in seconds): ";
            cin >> songLength;

            if (headList == NULL) {
                headList = tailList;
                tailList - > SetNext(new PlaylistNode(uniqueID, songName, artistName, songLength));
            } else {
                tailList - > SetNext(new PlaylistNode(uniqueID, songName, artistName, songLength));
                tailList = tailList - > GetNext();
            }
            break;
        }

    case 'd':
        {
            cout << "REMOVE SONG" << endl;

            cout << "Enter song's unique ID: ";
            cin >> uniqueID;

            currList = headList;
            prevList = headList;

            while (currList != NULL) {
                if (currList - > GetID() == uniqueID) {
                    if (currList == headList) {
                        headList = headList - > GetNext();

                        if (currList == tailList) {
                            tailList = NULL;
                        }
                    } else if (tailList == currList) {
                        tailList = prevList;
                        tailList - > SetNext(NULL);
                    } else {
                        prevList - > SetNext(currList - > GetNext());
                    }
                    break;
                }
                prevList = currList;
                currList = currList - > GetNext();
            }
            break;
        }

    case 'c':
        {
            cout << "CHANGE POSITION OF SONG" << endl;

            cout << "Enter song's current position: ";
            cin >> curPos;
            cout << "Enter new position for song: ";
            cin >> newPos;
            break;
        case 's':
                cout << "OUTPUT SONGS BY SPECIFIC ARTIST" << endl;
            cout << "Enter artist's name: ";
            getline(cin, artistName);

            currList = headList;
            position = 1;

            while (currList != NULL) {
                if (currList - > GetArtistName() == artistName) {
                    cout << position << "." << endl;
                    cout << "Unique ID: " << currList - > GetID() << endl;
                    cout << "Song Name: " << currList - > GetSongName() << endl;
                    cout << "Artist Name: " << currList - > GetArtistName() << endl;
                    cout << "Song Length (in seconds): " << currList - > GetSongLength() << endl;
                }
                currList = currList - > GetNext();
                position++;
            }
            break;
        }
    case 't':
        {
            cout << "OUTPUT TOTAL TIME OF PLAYLIST (IN SECONDS)" << endl;

            int totalLength = 0;
            currList = headList;

            while (currList != NULL) {
                totalLength += currList - > GetSongLength();
                currList = currList - > GetNext();
            }
            cout << "Total time: " << totalLength << " seconds" << endl;
            break;
        }
    case 'o':
        {
            cout << play << " - OUTPUT FULL PLAYLIST" << endl;

            if (headList == NULL) {
                cout << "Playlist is empty" << endl;
                break;
            }

            position = 1;
            currList = headList;

            cout << position << "." << endl;
            cout << "Unique ID: " << currList - > GetID() << endl;
            cout << "Song Name: " << currList - > GetSongName() << endl;
            cout << "Artist Name: " << currList - > GetArtistName() << endl;
            cout << "Song Length (in seconds): " << currList - > GetSongLength() << endl;

            currList = currList - > GetNext();
            position++;

            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I made the changes however, case a still terminates the program after it runs through.

Comment: What did you change? There is a return at the end of the loop which will exit the method.